# order by Month by fiscal year

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I have an excel spreadsheet which contains data like this

```
         Month         Value1   FY11Count     FY12COunt
         ----------------------------------------------
          jul          xxx      23             39
          aug          yy       33             49

          ..etc
```

I am using ODBC to query this data for a dashboard application. I would like to order this data by fiscal year (july,aug....etc till Jun) .
can i add another pseudo column say MonthNo and use some sort of logic to say when Month=Jul then 1, aug then 2..etc and order by that pseudocolumn?

Are there any other suggestions better than this?

Comment: that's probably the best way, but just throwing an alternate way out there. You could have a lookup table in your Excel spreadsheet that has Month | Month Number as columns, then add an extra column to your data with the Month Number and pick that up in your SQL. Depends on how your workflow is and how you want to "skin the cat"!

Comment: the problem i am running into is, i am using odbc and case statement does not seem to work well..however i do like you suggestion..just add a new work sheet and map monthno to Monthname and then join them and do a order by...Thanks!!!!!

Comment: great, if you get it working correctly, post your answer as the answer.

Comment: I used your idea to create a new worksheet and joined to get what i want.It worked great!! How do i accept your answer?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is not what you mean by "pseudocolumn", but SQL way is this:

```
order by case Month
           when 'jul' then 1
           when 'aug' then 2
           ...
         end
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is what i was going to do..but not sure thats possible in odbc excel sql!!

Comment: ok, it is a total nightmare trying to implement `case when` in microsoft query, the join suggestion in comments is much much simpler ;)

Comment: @Aprillion Where is the join suggestion? Deleted perhaps?

Comment: perhaps ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN Month(application_receiving_date) = 1 THEN 13 
    WHEN Month(application_receiving_date) = 2 THEN 14 
    WHEN Month(application_receiving_date) = 3 THEN 15                       
ELSE Month(application_receiving_date) END
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.